# Autocomplete in JQuery does not show hints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with autocomplete in JQuery. This is my autoComplete.html file: Text field appears on the page,but it doesn't show hints while typing. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
I've emended @Praveen Kumar answer to my code, but still TextBox doesn't show hints.

EDIT2:
Problem was in script link. Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
```

There should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
```

Now it works all right.
Now my code looks like this:

```
       <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    <meta name="description" content=""></meta>
    <meta name="author" content=""></meta>

    <title>Gigs Map Inserting</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="http:/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <!-- Linki do skryptow -->

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
          var availableTags = [
            "FirstOption",
            "SecondOption",
            "ThirdOption"
          ];
          $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
          });
        });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" ></script>



    </head>
<body>
<div th:class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Tags: </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of inclusion, update the references to the jQuery files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

Add a `source`:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "FirstOption",
    "SecondOption",
    "ThirdOption"
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

<div th:class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Tags: </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags" />
</div>
```